# Image not appearing

Tags: floats, diagrams, scaling, size

I included the graphicx, and used the following code, like normal, to include an image.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure1.png}
    \label{figure1}
    \caption[Impaired bacterial handling by macrophages when treated with the Glucose-6-phospahatase inhibitor for 5 days]{\emph{Figure legend}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure what went wrong. The warning says "the float is too large". Any idea what went wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Is the image not appearing at all or is it not appearing at the place you expect it to appear?

Comment: Can we see the image, have you tried scaling the height instead of the width, for example `height=0.9\textheight` thus leaving space for the caption.

Comment: side remark: put the \label *behind* \caption.

Answer (score 5):

I have compiled your code successfully with some random `.png` file. The height of your images is probably too large, you should try something like the following code.

If you want to change the caption globally you should also consider the following use of http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[textfont=it]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics
        [width=\textwidth, height=0.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]
        {figure1.png}
    \caption
        [Impaired bacterial handling by macrophages when treated with the Glucose-6-phospahatase inhibitor for 5 days]
        {Figure legend}
    \label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried changing the height, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @krithikabalagopal --- 'doesn't work' isn't very informative. What happens, exactly? Are there any warnings or error messages in the .log file?

Answer (score 1):

small variation of @Campanlgnis answer:

- if the width of yout image is biger than its height, than you include image as follows:

  `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bacteria-handling} % please use correct name of image ...`
- in contrary cases, when the height of image is bigger then its width, include image as follows

  `\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{bacteria-handling} % please use correct name of image ...`

If you will consider above "rules", image had to display in your document.

For the second case the complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[textfont=it]{caption}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{bacteria-handling} % please use correct name of image ...
\\[1ex]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    Figure legend: If the legend is long, i.e. has more lines, than you probably need to reduce image height, for example from \verb+height=0.85\textheight+ to \verb+height=0.8\textheight+.
\end{minipage}
    \caption[Impaired bacterial handling by macrophages]
            {Impaired bacterial handling by macrophages when treated with the Glucose-6-phospahatase inhibitor for 5 days}
    \label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

*Off-topic:* Usually a caption at figure show figure name and eventually legend, part, which go to the LoF, contain only (short) name of figure. However, you can write figure legend separately as it is anticipated in above MWE and in a contain write only short name for LoF and long name for figure caption.

[image]